# PHP: HTML Form disappears after submit

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've got a simple `<form>` in `myFunction`, as you can see here:

```
<?php
    function myFunction()
    {
        echo "
            <form method='post'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Something</legend>
                    <input type='text'>
                    <input type='submit' value='send' name='postform'>          
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        ";
            
        if (isset($_POST['postform']))
        {
            echo "I'm working!";
        }
    }
?>
```

When I call this function, I can see the form but, when I submit it (by clicking the submit button), it disappears. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the full code:

```php
<?php
    echo "
            <form method='post'>
            <button name='first'>First step</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        ";
    
    if (isset($_POST['first']))
    {
        myFunction();
    }
?>
   
<?php
    function myFunction()
    {
        echo "
        <form method='post'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Something</legend>
                <input type='text'>
                <input type='submit' value='send' name='postform'>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    ";
    
    if (isset($_POST['postform']))
    {
        echo "I'm working!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You mean the submit button disappears and the rest of the form stays there? That sounds like there is some client side javascript active. You will have to post that code too.

Comment: Everything seems to be working. I've pasted your code to [PHPTESTER](http://phptester.net/) ran the `myFunction()`. Submitted the form. The form is still visible and whole and you get the additional text.

Comment: No the whole form disappears, not only the button.

Comment: Can you Show us the code where you call your `myFunction()`?

Comment: there must be some other code that is overwriting the form code. But if you don't show other than this we cannot say

Comment: Okay I understand. This is my full code: https://shrib.com/gRCORN2bxBwuzmI?v=nc

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `$_POST` superglobal is purged on new request, just like when you're navigating through pages, which is quite natural.

So, if one comes to a page with, let's say, `$_POST = ['first' => '']`, and then he submits a post form (or any form) `['postform' => 'send']`, the resulting `$_POST` would be `['postform' => 'send']`.

So, in your case the easiest solution would be either to follow [Shailesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33606003/2044039) or submit the first form with `method='get'` and, of course, then you'll have to change `$_POST['first']` to `$_GET['first']`.

But a better solution would be to pass some 'step' parameter in request on each step, so you'll have `<input type="hidden" name="step" value="1">`. And then, depending on a step variable, do some stuff.

Also check out `$_SESSION`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It disappears because you don't get to call the function myFunction() itself. The second form does not include the field "first".

If you want it to work "as is", include this in myFunction() code:

```
    function myFunction()
    {
    echo "
    <form method='post'>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Something</legend>
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='hidden' value='send' name='first'>
    <input type='submit' value='send' name='postform'>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
   ";
   if (isset($_POST['postform']))
   {
    echo "I'm working!";
   }
   }
   ?>
```

The only change is

```
    <input type='hidden' value='send' name='first'>
```

which makes the form visible again. Anyway, you should rethink this whole code.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I quite don't get it why it works when you add this hidden input. Could you explain it please?

Comment: You are checking for the existence of a "first" value coming from the input form, regardless it real value, in order to call the function myFunction(), which is what echoes the HTML form. With that hidden value, we enter the "if" block in your main code, and then call the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['first']))
{
   myFunction();
}
```

Replace with:

```
if (isset($_POST['first']) || isset($_POST['postform']) )
{
   myFunction();
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. But could you please explain to me what the difference is and why it works like this? Would appreciate it.

Comment: There are two forms in your page. so you have to check both submit value is set or not in if condition. so that your function will call on both submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Move your *postform* form processing out of the *myFunction* function definition and call *myFunction* function from there. Here's the complete code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "
        <form method='post'>
            <button name='first'>First step</button>
        </form>
    ";

    if (isset($_POST['first'])){
        myFunction();
    }

?>

<?php
    function myFunction(){
        echo "
            <form method='post'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Something</legend>
                    <input type='text'>
                    <input type='submit' value='send' name='postform'>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        ";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['postform'])){
        myFunction();
        echo "I'm working!";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

write the same as two different documents.

```
<html>
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="submit.php">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Something</legend>
   <input type="text" name="input">
   <input type='submit' value='send' name="postform">
   </fieldset>
   </form>
```

now write the following in submit.php

```
 <?php 
  $input=$_POST['input'];
    if ($input!="")
     {
    echo "I'm working!";
      }

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I need to have all in one document.

Comment: then in that case try using  action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " in your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name."; 
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this place on this code:

```
<?php
echo "
<form method='post'>
<button name='first'>First step</button>
</form>
</div>
";

if (isset($_POST['first']) or isset($_POST['postform']))
{
myFunction();
}

?>
```